# c++ design issue about inheritance, dynamic cast or virtual functions?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I have a baseclass with some private members that have the same type for every subclass. Every subclass has his own members (some more than others). I store pointers in a list of baseclass* type to every subclass member.

So I could use virtual functions to call public members of my subclass. But In some subclasses I won't have functions to replace.(But I don't think that's a problem unless I try to call it to a certain subclasses) 
The other method is to dynamic cast the the pointer from a baseclass to the right subclass and call his members.

How would you do it? Why would I do one method instead of the other?

Comment: You're not very clear about what you want to do. Can you try to make your question more precise, or include sample code?

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to, can you please post an example of your classes structure?

Comment: Please see the [How To Ask Questions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), when asking a 'how do I?' you should post a sample of the code you are working with so that people can answer you in context and also because it's easier to understand what you're doing/trying to do when we see the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to use `dynamic_cast` usually suggests a flaw in design (or need to conform to some external constraints). So you should design so that you don't need it.

You use a base interface when you're handling different types of objects in some uniform way. This means the base interface should be complete enough to provide all operations you will want to perform in such case. If some operations don't make sense for some subclasses, there are two possible scenarios:

1. The operation is a no-op for the subclass, but it still forms a part of how the class is to be used. In such case, just implement the subclass function as empty.
2. The operation makes no sense whatsoever for the subclass. In that case, it should probably not be part of the base interface, and more importantly, it shouldn't be needed there. If you need a subclass-specific functionality, you probably don't need it when handling a generic collection. That's what your design should ensure.

Comment: Are you saying that if I declare a virtual function in my baseclass, that I should have a function with the same name in each and everysubclass? So then it's better to dynamic cast?

Comment: @user2321611 you don't have to. You may want to implement some default behavior in baseclass function, such as throwing an exception. As it was said, don't use dynamic casts.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to use `virtual` functions assuming you have heterogeneous sequences of you objects: using `dynamic_cast<>()` tends to be quite slow and if you don't know the type of your objects you'll need to cast a lot.

Note that for using objects data members actually shall not matter! You look at the object through its publuc functions. Data members are normally all private (there are very few exceptions and these are only borderline data, e.g., a registry for event handlers may be a public data member).